# Uploading a file to a specif server in azure

Tags: azure

I have a site to site connection established in Azure to a machine, and I have created a shared folder in that machine and now I have created an application where I am trying to upload a file and when I am running from visual studio I am able to upload the file in to the specific server but when I am deploying to Azure cloud services, it is giving an error as \10.1.0.xxxx\abc path not found. what can be the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

I was confused a bit from your question. When you said 'site to site connection' did you mean you created a virtual network and point to site VPN between your virtual machine and your desktop?

Well if you are using windows azure virtual machine you should be able to create a shared folder and upload files from your local desktop. Just need to create a virtual network and build a VPN between that machine and your desktop. But it might be impossible if you wanted to upload file to your cloud service. You might be able to open the firewall port on your cloud service virtual machine through powershell and startup task but all files you uploaded will be cleared when your cloud service virtual machine was moved by azure fabric controller.